# How to crawl urls from sitemap whose modified date has changed using scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, sitemap

I'm trying to implement an incremental crawler but in this case instead of matching the url I'm trying to match the  attribute of sitemap xml to check if the page is modified or not. Right now the problem is I'm not able to find a way to decipher where should I intercept the request which gets the sitemap url so that I can add logic to look from a stored `<lastmod>` value and return only those url whose value is changed.

Here's the xml:

```
<url>
<loc>https://www.example.com/hello?id=1</loc>
<lastmod>2017-12-03</lastmod>
<changefreq>Daily</changefreq>
<priority>1.0</priority>
</url>
```

Sitemap spider:

```
class ExampleSpider(SitemapSpider):
  name = "example"
  allowed_domains = []
  sitemap_urls = ["https://www.example.com/sitemaps.xml"]
  sitemap_rules = [
    ('/hello/', 'parse_data')
  ]

  def parse_data(self,response):
    pass
```

My question is: Is it possible to override the sitemap `_parse_sitemap` function ? As of now I had found that scrapy's [sitemap](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/sitemap.py) spider only look for `<loc>` attribute. Can I override it using `process_request` just like we use to do in normal spiders ?

Comment: can you try to override `_parse_sitemap` ? You can find source code of this spider on disk (`import scrapy.spiders ; print(scrapy.spiders.__file__)`) and see how it works, and make own version.

Comment: instead, just scrape the sitemap URL using `start_requests()` method of scrapy and parse the resultant XML in your callback function.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is to get the value of the `lastmod` and then crawl every `loc` that meets some condition then this should work:

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
  name = "example"
  start_urls = ["https://www.example.com/sitemaps.xml"]

  def parse(self, response):
    sitemap = scrapy.selector.XmlXPathSelector(response)
    sitemap.register_namespace(
      # ns is just a namespace and the second param should be whatever the 
      # xmlns of your sitemap is
      'ns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'
    )
    # this gets you a list of all the "loc" and "last modified" fields.
    locsList = sitemap.select('//ns:loc/text()').extract()
    lastModifiedList = sitemap.select('//ns:lastmod/text()').extract()

    # zip() the 2 lists together
    pageList = list(zip(locsList, lastModifiedList))

    for page in pageList:
      url, lastMod = page
      if r.search(r'\/hello\/', url) and lastMod # ... add the rest of your condition for list modified here:
        # crawl the url
        yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_data)

  def parse_data(self,response):
    pass
```